# Textarea &nbsp; alert() converts to a Space

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a textarea, where I insert 4 lines with `&nbsp;` when I `alert()` the output it converts it to a space, is there any function in jQuery that would display as it and keep it the same ? the expected output should be the same I have added to textarea without converting `&nbsp;` to space.

jSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s4kjpLqg/

Comment: I can use .html() however the content is saved in a variable. so if I used content.html() that doesnt work.

Comment: Are you trying to display in the alert, the same formatting of the textarea?

Comment: @Themer no, like `var content = $("#first").html();`

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you need to format an alert in a specific way I'd suggest using a library to do it instead of the standard `alert()` control

Comment: thanks guys.. the problem is the content I have used in textarea comes from a variable that includes `&nbsp;` however when I alert() it, it changes it to SPACE. I have to add that content back to tinyMCE but there id adds as a SPACE, however if its properly `&nbsp;` it works fine. thanks once again..

Answer (score 5):

Use `$("#first").html();` instead of `$("#first").val();`

**Result:**

```js
var content = $("#first").html();
alert(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="first">this is new

&nbsp;

222222222222

&nbsp;

3333333333333

&nbsp;

4444444444
</textarea>
```

Comment: The author has clarified "I can use .html() however the content is saved in a variable. so if I used content.html() that doesnt work". Maybe you should add a snippet to show him it just works as he expects.

Comment: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/s4kjpLqg/1/) here is your updated jsfiddle with @VaLLe 's answer.

Comment: @zurfyx Thanks for your hint, I overlooked his comment